# Windows Server making hard disk accessible after moving to a new installation

Tags: windows-server-2003, hard-drive, sata

I have a serial ata disk running windows server 2003 in an old setup and now our company wanted to upgrade the system. We got a new computer and I transfer the hard disk from one setup to the other. Now every time I boot the computer I see the logo and I get prompted to choose safe mode or continue booting normally. In both cases I end up with a blue screen.

I am receiving a `Stop 0x0000007B error` which according to Microsoft forums is mentioned as `INACCESSIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE`.

How can I make my hard disk accessible again?

Comment: Are the disk controllers the same across these two servers?  Did you get the STOP code -- is it `0x0000007B`?

Comment: @jscott yes this is the code I am getting.

Answer (score 5):

You disks are inaccessible because the driver  required to read them on the new system isn't loaded.  What you could try is putting them back in the old system, add the new controller to the old system, verify that it works, then put the new card in the new system and attach the drives.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the old setup anymore so I was wondering if there is a way to make it search and replace the existing one with the one that it needs.

Answer (score 1):

This won't help you this time, but next time you move a disk, goto device manager, then uninstall/remove the disk controller, then shutdown and move to the new machine. This will force Windows to find and install a compatible controller driver before attempting to boot. This has worked great for me moving from IDE to SATA to SAS.